# Creating dynamic Key-Value pairs in logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have the following data in logstash output:

"Details" => "SAID,:EGT1_M2P7_01,::LIP,:10-168-98-203::RIP,:10-81-122-84:",

I want to make dynamic Key-value pairs according to delimiters

",:" means that "SAID" is the key and "EGT1_M2P7_01" is the value
"::" means that it is a new line and again ",:" means that "LIP" is the key and "10-168-98-203" is the value.

Need to know how to do it. Looking forward for answers

Comment: Welcome. you need to show us what you have tried. That is not right way to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

for the input you have given

`"SAID,:EGT1_M2P7_01,::LIP,:10-168-98-203::RIP,:10-81-122-84:"`

this `filter plugin` and `stdout`

```
filter {
 
       kv {
            source => "Details"
            field_split => "::"
            value_split => ":"
       }

       mutate {
            remove_field => ["host", "@timestamp","@version", "message", "sequence" ]
       }

}

output {
    
     stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
     }

}
```

gives you

```
{
     "LIP," => "10-168-98-203",
    "SAID," => "EGT1_M2P7_01,",
     "RIP," => "10-81-122-84"
}
```

remove the additional fields that are specific to your host system by adding in above `remove_field` list.

Comment: Thanks, that was perfect. But now in the same output i have another data like this:
"Details" => "SAID,REASON,:EGT1_M2P7_01,1::LIP,:10-168-98-203::RIP,:10-81-122-84:::HOSTID:M2P2:",

Here in the first block i should get SAID=EGT1_M2P7_01 and REASON=1.

how should i handle this?

Comment: accept the solution for the original question you posted. if you need to ask another question, post a new question.